# Use Dataframes to identify sessions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

For an user analysis I have a database with events and a timestamp for each.

```
Timestamp   |   user    |    event code
13:30:23    |   user1   |    event123
13:30:45    |   user1   |    event123
13:30:56    |   user3   |    event123
13:40:15    |   user2   |    event123
13:55:20    |   user1   |    event123
```

Now I want to identify "sessions" for each user by annotating the events with a session id.

Each session should be identified by a group of events for an user, that don't have a X seconds(or minutes) gap in between them. That means a X second gap after an event closes a session. 
Session  ids don't have to start by 0 for each user, but are later on used on a per user basis only. Here X = 5 Minutes is set.

```
Timestamp   |   user    |    event code    | session_id
13:30:23    |   user1   |    event123      | 1
13:30:45    |   user1   |    event123      | 1
13:30:56    |   user3   |    event123      | 2
13:40:15    |   user2   |    event123      | 3
13:55:20    |   user1   |    event123      | 4
```

Is this possible with dataframes?

Comment: What is `X` in sample data?

Comment: I thought about 5 minutes. Depending on how reasonable the resulting sessions are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
#convert to datetimes
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
#identify difference 5Min for each group with cumulative sum
g = (df.groupby('user')['Timestamp'].diff() > pd.Timedelta('5Min')).cumsum()
#create counter of groups
df['session_id'] = df.groupby(['user', g], sort=False).ngroup() + 1
print (df)
            Timestamp   user event code  session_id
0 2019-01-07 13:30:23  user1   event123           1
1 2019-01-07 13:30:45  user1   event123           1
2 2019-01-07 13:30:56  user3   event123           2
3 2019-01-07 13:40:15  user2   event123           3
4 2019-01-07 13:55:20  user1   event123           4
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you really much.

Comment: One thing I already did, but needs to be mentioned is, that the "Timestamp" field needs to be ordered, doesn't it?

Comment: @FelixJ. - Yes, exaclty. If not, use `df = df.sort_values('Timestamp')`